# Imgur is misbehaving!

Tags: bug, status-norepro, profile-picture, imgur

As of right now, I don't seem to be able to load my profile picture. Nor a bunch of others. Nor even some images in posts. My profile looks like this when I load it:

> [image: My busted profile]

And here is the MSE users page:

> [image: Busted MSE Users page]

Browser developer tools indicate I'm getting to the server, and it's sending back a 404, with the response body being the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
    <Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
    <BucketName>i.stack.imgur.com</BucketName>
    <RequestId>5AF32B5D1A1F83FA</RequestId>
    <HostId>XClSHkzldpcUQUk2v3zE5EmjQoxTqSntgy/AqVUZrJBw93+//ygbp1iQGmqY0cir</HostId>
</Error>
```

In fact, while typing this post in, the preview is showing the second of the above images, but not the first. Both uploaded identically via the Upload Image button.

<sub>For reference: Win 7, IE11, all patched, no plugins or userscripts</sub>

Edit: The problem seems to be intermittent somewhat, and to keep hopping around; images that failed to load a few minutes ago start working, while others start failing. Also, it's happening across multiple browsers. Sometimes, an image will fail, but then the same image will also succeed, but with different size parameters. But those same parameters that worked, don't work on another image.

Comment: No-repro from Safari 6.1.

Comment: Are you at work?  Or behind a firewall?  I generally can't see imgr images at work at all because the firewall blocks it.

Comment: Nope, at home. Happens on Firefox too. And it's not all imgur images, even; seems to be hopping around. In fact, I'll just edit in some more info.

Comment: Bug found in [chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2080636#2080636). But that's the only one I can reproduce.

Comment: I just reproduced this after trying to rehost an image. It seems to have uploaded successfully, but [the resulting image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WTDq.png) doesn't work for me.

Comment: I can repro at [this tag wiki](http://anime.stackexchange.com/tags/ergo-proxy/info) ([image link](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LZpIY.jpg)) on Chrome 35 / Windows 7 / a home network with a non-misbehaving firewall.

Comment: Sounds to me like a DNS issue. I know this sounds a little silly, but can you try rebooting your router?

Comment: @TravisJ DNS should, I would think, stop me from getting all images, or none, wouldn't it?

Comment: @BillyMailman - I believe that if the DNS has cached a bad route for one of the content delivery networks you may only get the data from a subset of them leading to that behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce this issue at this time. I've seen imgur have issues in the past (both with Stack account and anonymous hosting) so my best guess is that on May 31 imgur had some performance or routing issues. I did some Googling and found some anecdotal evidence to indicate that the issue was widespread on May 31, though nothing concrete. Bottom line is it's working now.